# How to know is a row in table view is added

Tags: objective-c, delegates, nstableview

I have a project that uses core data, where there is an array controller which holds the data of the table view (created with core data).
I need to set editable the first column of any row added (the insertion is triggered with a button).
I tried to implement NSTableViewDelegate where there's the method:

```
- (void) tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView didAddRowView:(NSTableRowView *)rowView forRow:
```

But the problem is that everytime I add a row, this method gets invoked not one time, but one time for each row, so if I have a table of 10 rows and I insert a new one, the method gets invoked 11 times.So I don't really know when a new object is added.
How do I get around this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I presume you are using `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` to perform the insertion. In this method, make note of the current count of objects in the table view. And in the didAddRowView method merely query the count of rows in the tableView object and if it sums to be one more than the initial count, then you know the row has been added.

In all honesty though you know when a row is being added when the user taps on the button to add a row to the table view, so you should assume that a row has been inserted rather than resorting to this non-elegant way of doing it. I propose this because row inserts are pretty much instant (unless you are doing some sort of large operation which causes delay).

Comment: I have used no code for the insertion, I have just used an array controller, the add button is bound with the array controller with controller key: canInsert.

Comment: It's all done with core data and interface builder, there's no code.

Comment: Well, this represents the limitations of using a xib then. I would suggest you tie the add button in the xib to code so that you know exactly when it has been tapped. Once that is done, you can assume a row has been added upon that button press and as long as there were no errors reported from Core Data.

Comment: (also, it's NSTableView in this case, not UITableView)